# Unsuccessful adding image to header with Open XML SDK in word document

Tags: c#, openxml

This is only the second time I use OpenXML sdk (2.5) and I'm trying to add an image to a the header of the document. But without any luck, the only thing displayed in the document is the test text I placed in the body. I have followed the directions in MSDN to create the header and I have a helper function like this:

```
private static DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Header GeneratePageHeaderPart(WordprocessingDocument myDoc, string relationshipId)
    {
     string imageFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/Docs");
        string[] encabezado = { "logoCideAsistencia.jpg", "logoSegobAsistencia.jpg", "logoPFAsistencia.jpg", "logoDiplomadoAsistencia.jpg" }; 
     var element =
     new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing (
     new DW.Inline(
         new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
         new DW.EffectExtent()
         {
             LeftEdge = 0L,
             TopEdge = 0L,
             RightEdge = 0L,
             BottomEdge = 0L
         },
         new DW.DocProperties()
         {
             Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
             Name = "Picture 1"
         },
         new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
             new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
         new A.Graphic(
             new A.GraphicData(
                 new PIC.Picture(
                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                         new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                         {
                             Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                             Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                         },
                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                     new PIC.BlipFill(
                         new A.Blip(
                             new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                 new A.BlipExtension()
                                 {
                                     Uri =
                                       "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                 })
                         )
                         {
                             Embed = relationshipId,
                             CompressionState =
                             A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                         },
                         new A.Stretch(
                             new A.FillRectangle())),
                     new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                         new A.Transform2D(
                             new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                             new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                         new A.PresetGeometry(
                             new A.AdjustValueList()
                         ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
             ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
     )
     {
         DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
         EditId = "50D07946"
     });


            var header = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Header();
            var parrafo = new Paragraph();
            var run = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run();
            run.Append(element);
            parrafo.Append(run);
            header.Append(parrafo);
            return header;
    }
```

Then in my controller function (I'm working with ASP MVC) I call it like this:

```
 public ActionResult PrintHorarioModulo(int IdCurso)
    {

        string document = "HorariodelModulo.docx";
        string uploadsFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Docs");
        string imageFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/Docs");
        string[] encabezado = { "logoCideAsistencia.jpg", "logoSegobAsistencia.jpg", "logoPFAsistencia.jpg", "logoDiplomadoAsistencia.jpg" };
        string ruta = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, document);
        using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ruta, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            GenerateMainDocumentPart().Save(mainPart);
            var documentSettingsPart =mainPart.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>("rId1");
            GenerateDocumentSettingsPart().Save(documentSettingsPart);
            var header = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("rId2");
            ImagePart headerImg1 = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
            string ruta_imagen = Path.Combine(imageFolder, encabezado[0]);
            using (Stream targetStream = headerImg1.GetStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(ruta_imagen, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    while (bytesread > 0)
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
                        bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    }
                }
            }
            string relationshipId = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(headerImg1);
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Header cabeza = GeneratePageHeaderPart(myDoc, relationshipId);
            cabeza.Save(header);
            header.Header = cabeza;

     }
```

I cannot possibly figure out what is wrong, when I debug I see that the run is populated with the DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Drawing object alright, but then nothing shows in the document. Even the variable `header` of the controller function has a Drawing object, but the document is still blank. Ah! and did I mention the page orientation remains portrait as well? Please help this are my first attempts at Open XML

I updated my code because I realized I was adding the ImagePart to the document as a whole and not to the header, but still no results, the code now reads:

```
var header = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("rId2");
            ImagePart headerImg1 = header.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/jpeg", "rId3");
            string ruta_imagen = Path.Combine(imageFolder, encabezado[0]);
            string relationshipId = header.GetIdOfPart(headerImg1);
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Header cabeza = GeneratePageHeaderPart(myDoc, relationshipId);
            header.Header = cabeza;
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(ruta_imagen, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    headerImg1.FeedData(fs);
                }
```

So until now I haven't been able to insert the image in the header, but I have been able to insert it in the body, the code now looks like:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ruta, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            ImagePart headerImg1 = mainPart.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/jpeg", "rId3");
            GenerateMainDocumentPart().Save(mainPart);
            var documentSettingsPart =mainPart.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>("rId1");
            GenerateDocumentSettingsPart().Save(documentSettingsPart);
            var header = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("rId2");
            ImagePart headerImg2 = header.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/jpeg", "rId4");
            string ruta_imagen = Path.Combine(imageFolder, encabezado[3]);
            string relationshipId = header.GetIdOfPart(headerImg2);
            GeneratePageHeaderPart(myDoc, relationshipId, header);


                using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(ruta_imagen, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    fs.Position = 0;
                    headerImg1.FeedData(fs);
                }



     }
```

And the code to generate the body is almost identical, (which is why I don't understand what I'm doing wrong):

```
private static Document GenerateMainDocumentPart()
    {
        var elem = new Document(new Body(
            new Paragraph(
                new ParagraphProperties(
                        new SectionProperties(
                        new PageSize(){
                          Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape
            }),
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(
                    new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text("Page 1 content"))


                        )
            ),
            new Paragraph(
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(
     new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing (
     new DW.Inline(
         new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
         new DW.EffectExtent()
         {
             LeftEdge = 0L,
             TopEdge = 0L,
             RightEdge = 0L,
             BottomEdge = 0L
         },
         new DW.DocProperties()
         {
             Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
             Name = "Picture 1"
         },
         new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
             new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
         new A.Graphic(
             new A.GraphicData(
                 new PIC.Picture(
                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                         new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                         {
                             Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                             Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                         },
                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                     new PIC.BlipFill(
                         new A.Blip(
                             new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                 new A.BlipExtension()
                                 {
                                     Uri =
                                       "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                 })
                         )
                         {
                             Embed = "rId3",
                             CompressionState =
                             A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                         },
                         new A.Stretch(
                             new A.FillRectangle())),
                     new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                         new A.Transform2D(
                             new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                             new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                         new A.PresetGeometry(
                             new A.AdjustValueList()
                         ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
             ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
     )
     {
         DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
         EditId = "50D07946"
     }))),

            new SectionProperties(
                    new HeaderReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.First,
                        Id = "rId2"
                    })));
        return elem;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to try using the Open XML Productivity Tool in the SDK (found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). The tool lets you open existing documents and inspect the parts and xml within those parts. When you select an element in the tree, you can go to "Reflect Code" to see what code you would use to construct the selected content. So just create a file similar to what you're trying to create, open it with the tool, and see what code is needed to generate it.

Comment: @MikeDour I've done it, I even copy/pasted the code from the tool (just changed the embed attribute to point to my id) but without results. I know there's something I'm missing because I have been able to insert the image in the body of the document using this `ImagePart headerImg1 = mainPart.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/jpeg", "rId3");
                GenerateMainDocumentPart().Save(mainPart);` but the header is problematic